# Iterate over a file using two values on the same line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need pass a series of couples values which are arguments for a c++ software. So I wrote this script:

```
while read randomNumbers; do
                lambda = $randomNumbers | cut -f1 -d ' '
                mi = $randomNumbers | cut -f2 -d ' '
                ./queueSim mm1-queue $lambda $mi 
done < "randomNumbers"
```

where the first arg is the first value for each line in the file "randomNumbers" and the second one in the second value (of course). I got a segfault and a "command not found".

How can I assign to lambda and mi valus got from the line and pass this variable to c++ software?

Comment: Paste the output of your script as well. Most probably it's not bash (or cut) which segfaults...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for cut.  Let read split the line for you:

```
while read lambda mi; do
    ./queueSim mm1-queue $lambda $mi 
done < randomNumbers
```

Note that it is also commonly used in conjunction with IFS to split the input line on different fields.  For example, to parse `/etc/passwd` ( a file with colon separated lines ), you will often see:

```
while IFS=: read username passwd uid gid info home shell; do ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend assigning the values like this:

```
lambda=$(echo $randomNumbers | cut -f1 -d ' ')
mi=$(echo $randomNumbers | cut -f2 -d ' ')
```

the way you do it, you actually try to run a command that is named like whatever is the current content of `$randomNumbers`.

**Edit:**
Another thing: since your columns are delimited by a whitespace character, you could also just read the entire line into an array whose elements are separated by whitespaces as well. One way to achieve this is:

```
columns=( $(echo "$randomNumbers" | grep -o "[^ ]*") )
./queueSim mm1-queue ${columns[@]::2}
```

The first line matches all substrings that are not containing any spaces separately and puts them into the array `columns`. The second line does the same thing as the corresponding one in your implementation: inserting the first two columns as parameters. Since is done with slicing: you take the entire array `${columns[@]}`, but select a certain subsequence of it by applying the boundary `::2` on the right, which returns in every element of `columns` beginning from the left (position `0`), that is not on a position `>=2`.